# Deploying project to live server with Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I've usually used another platform such as DeployHQ for deploying projects but in this instance, I have a local repository set up which pushes to the remote repository in Gitlab but how can I then push the remote repository to the live server?

Do I need to create a post-receive web hook for this in Gitlab and if so, can someone advise on what it is that I require?

I have tried searching the documentation and not found instructions for what it is I require but I'm probably not searching for the right thing.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't the live server poll gitlab for changes. This is how Jenkins CI normally is set up.

Comment: I have installed git on the production server, I would imagine it could pull Gitlab yes, if I knew how I could implement that also. I am currently trying to follow [this guide](http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/).

Comment: You want it to be automatic?

Comment: Ideally yes @RobbieAverill, so that when we push to remote repo, it also deploys on production server.

Comment: What are you trying to deploy exactly?

Comment: Changes to local (dev) files @st0ph - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a GitLab CI runner on your production server or if you have another one set up a deployment server with the runner installed. To install a runner on a server please refer to [this guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner#installation).

Then you need to configure your repository with a `gitlab-ci.yml` file which you place in the root folder of your repository. In this file you specify where specific files and folders go (using copy), build files or do whatever you must to do get things up and running. A guide for setting up such a file can be found [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html).